# IndexSearcher help in Solr 3.5.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, solr, lucene

I was using Solr 1.3.0 for my eCommerce application and now I'm planning to implement Solr 3.5.0. In Indexsearcher.java we are passing some subreaders (with doc base) of reader unlike in solr 1.3 where we would pass a entire reader.

Can anyone help me where and what basis the subreader is generated?

Thanks.
Jeyaprakash

```
public void search(Weight weight, Filter filter, Collector collector)
  throws IOException {

// TODO: should we make this
// threaded...?  the Collector could be sync'd?


    System.out.println("Total number of sub readers is  "+subReaders.length);

    // always use single thread:
for (int i = 0; i < subReaders.length; i++) { 
  System.out.println("The value of Doc base passed is "+docBase + docStarts[i]);
  System.out.println("The Number in sub reader is "+subReaders[i].numDocs());
  // search each subreader
  collector.setNextReader(subReaders[i], docBase + docStarts[i]);
  final Scorer scorer = (filter == null) ?
    weight.scorer(subReaders[i], !collector.acceptsDocsOutOfOrder(), true) :
    FilteredQuery.getFilteredScorer(subReaders[i], getSimilarity(), weight, weight, filter);
  if (scorer != null) {
    scorer.score(collector);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you paste a relevant piece of code?

Comment: I have added the code from IndexSearxher.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of time, sub readers are readers for a single segment. The point is to have more fine-grained control over the readers, and better performance when you know which segment you are interested in.

For example, when committing a new segment, having segment readers allows you to only load the field cache for the newly committed segment instead of reloading the field cache for the whole index (which is way faster and prevents duplication of the cache entries).

Uwe Schindler and Simon Willnauer have written very nice articles on this topic:

- [Uwe Says: is your Reader atomic?](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/uwe-says%3a-is-your-reader-atomic)
- [Simon says: optimize is bad for you....](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/simon-says%3a-optimize-is-bad-for-you)